# C2DM registration failed because same auth_key

Tags: android, emulation, android-c2dm, user-registration

I'm currently testing my c2dm app on a notebook. I used two emulator to test the communication between my server & client devices. The problem is the second device failed to register to my server because it has the same [auth_token] as the first device. (Both of them have a different valid gmail account). Is there anyone can help so I can use two (or more) emulators with different [auth_token]? Thanks before.. :)

Answer (score 0):

i used above code for registering

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
boolean isRegistrationId = wmbPreference1.getBoolean("RegistrationId", true);
    if(isRegistrationId)
       {

            Log.w("C2DM", "start registration process");
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
             editor.putBoolean("RegistrationId", false);
              editor.commit();
              Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
intent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(put here your current acitivity.this, 0, new Intent(), 0));`


     intent.putExtra("sender", "xyz@gmail.com");//put here different gmail id 
                    startService(intent);
                       }
```

and used class below to receive registration id....

```
public class C2DMRegistrationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
            Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
            final String registrationId = intent
                    .getStringExtra("registration_id");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
            Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID"+registrationId);
            Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                    + ", error = " + error);
            String deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            Log.w("C2DM", "Received device ID"+deviceId);


        }
    }
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thx for reply, I have done that part before. Everything works fine when I tested my app on one emulator. Now the problem is I want to use two emulators. The second one failed to register because same registration_id (which is used as an auth_token) is given by c2dm server. We cant have 2 devices with same registration_id (or auth_token) right? So, how can I make my emulators got a different registration_id. Thx again..

Comment: well man above code works fine for me even with second emulator and i get different id.Ensure that whatever gmail id you are using in above code is the same with which you have signed in emulator->setting->account n sync

Answer (score -1):

We cant test C2DM in Simulators. Because it requires market app in device to get registered for C2DM server. and also the market app need to be signed in. SO that the app will run flawlessly.

Comment: Hi Pavandroid, thx for reply. is that so? Because my app works fine on the first emulator. It is just the second one failed to register due to registration_id (or auth_token) duplication.

Comment: I am sure. But do u have Maket app in simulator/s?

Comment: Hmm... i don't see Market app on my emulator but (dunno why) c2dm still works fine for me. AFAIK, we can test c2dm on emulator with GoogleAPIs level 8 & a valid gmail account..

Comment: Pavandroid, you are wrong: "To develop and test on the Android Emulator, you need to download the Android 2.2 version of the Google APIs Add-On" Source: https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#testing